# What kind of LayoutParams should I use?

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem description:

I have a customized ImageView:

```
public class TestImageView extends ImageView {
...
    public void onImageLoaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width = DeviceInfo.getScreenWidth();
        int height = width * (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
                new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(width, height);
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Then I received this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

In my project I did make an instance of TestImageView the child of a FrameLayout. So if I change ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams to FrameLayout.LayoutParams it will work. But this customized ImageView could be inside other kind of layouts like LinearLayout. I don't think I should restrict it to FrameLayout.layoutParams here.

So what should I do here? More generally, why Android make different LayoutParams? The LayoutParams classes seems identical? I don't see a necessity.

Comment: Have you tried using LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through some source code in the Android framework. I think I am not doing the right thing:

Layouting should be the job of a View's parent!!

So I shouldn't put the code in TestImageView. Instead it should be placed in the parent of the View:

```
public class ParentOfTestImageView extends LinearLayout {
...
...
...
    public void whateverFunction() {
        TestImageView imageView = new TestImageView(context);
        // Note here
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(whateverWidth, whateverHeight);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each subclass of ViewGroup has its own LayoutParams (descending from ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams which is descendent from ViewGroup.LayoutParams (There are no MarginLayoutParams for each of the subclasses as the margin setting functionality is available through inheritance)), because they support different qualities. For example a LinearLayout.LayoutParams supports the use of gravity. So, depending on whatever type of ViewGroup your ImageView is held in, your LayoutParams will have to be that same type, or at least cast to that same type. You have a couple of options. One is to assume in the subclass you made of ImageView that you will always be using a certain type of layout, and then substitute ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams for (your layout type).LayoutParams. But if you ever change that, it will cease to work, so you can avoid all of this by using generics:

```
public class TestImageView<I extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> extends ImageView {
    public void onImageLoaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width = DeviceInfo.getScreenWidth();
        int height = width * (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
        I layoutParams = (I)
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height);
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

and its use:

```
// using a RelativeLayout
TestImageView<RelativeLayout.LayoutParams> iv = new TestImageView<>();
```

I hope this helps you out! (I currently don't have my testing device on me though, so drop a comment if it isn't working)

Comment: Generics isn't necessary here, but otherwise this is correct. ViewGroup.LayoutParams is the base class of all LayoutParams. Since he is not relying on margins, he can simply replace MarginLayoutParams with :ayou